Making a textarea visible when a <p> is hovered
I want the <div id="Feedback"> to appear when I hover over <p>Would you like to give feedback?</p>. In other words, I want the <textarea> and <p>How can we imporve the page?</p> to have their display set to 'block' when I hover over that p element.
Heres what I tried:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sign up</title>
    <link href="./account.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="entire-form">
      <form action="form.html" method="GET">
        <h1><b>Sign up =)</b></h1>
        <div id="Feedback">
                  <p>Would you like to give feedback?</p>
                  <p>How can we imporve the page?</p>
                  <textarea name="improve" id="improve" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea>
        </div>
      </form> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

textarea, #Feedback p{
    display: none;
}

#Feedback p:nth-child(1) {
    /*What this does is it looks in the div with the id Feedback and its p elements and selects the first child i.e. the p that comes first*/
    display: block;
    margin: 15px;
}

#Feedback p:nth-child(1):hover{
    display: block;
}


If you want is " Show text area and 'How can we improve the page?' when you hover on 'Would you like to give feedback?'then this will help you also you can achieve that with html and css only.
I have added class someCss & hiddenContent. Add hiddenContent to div which you want to hide. Most css I have added is basic but this .someCss:hover ~ .hiddenContent{ display:block;} is important as it adds display: block to hiddenContent when you hover on someCss text. I have explained in stort as its simple.
Below is working example.


.hiddenContent {
  display: none
}

.someCss:hover~.hiddenContent {
  display: block;
}
<div id="Feedback">
  <p class="someCss">Would you like to give feedback?</p>
  <p class="hiddenContent">How can we imporve the page?</p>
  <textarea class="hiddenContent" name="improve" id="improve" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea>
</div>




THANKS SO MUCH. But I wanted to ask something. Why do we set the display to block two times and I am a beginner so I don't have much experience. Could u also explain what this ~ means?

@TalhaSaleemi It was supposed to keep textarea visible when hovering but I haven't add all of it so sorry for that confusion.

Oh so even if I dont write that part, when I hover over p, the text area will appear but as soon as I move my cursor, it will disappear right?

@TalhaSaleemi Yes.
